# Cardinality in ER Diagram / 1 to many

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, erd, cardinality

I'm trying to create my first ER diagram but I am confused what type of cardinality I should use.

The entities are: **Order** and **Product**

The assumption is that each order can include one or many products

Should the cardinality between order and product be 1:N or N:M ?

[Order]--1--includes--N--[Product]

Comment: There have been many examples of this type of relationship between Order and Product. You can add an additional OrderDetail. The ERD should look like this: [Order] -1-N-[OrderDetail]-N-1-[Product]. Ex: NorthWind database: https://documentation.red-gate.com/dms6/data-mask

Answer (score 0):

The following notation

```
[Order]--1--includes--N--[Product]
```

says that a product can be included in 1 order and an order can include N products.  This corresponds to a 1:N cardinality.

However this does not correspond to the reality of the order/product relationship.  A same product can in general appear in many orders.  And an order can have many products.  So the cardinality should be N:M:

```
[Order]--N--includes--M--[Product]
```